# Syntax of C++ class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm not so sure I understand the syntax of the constructor of this `Person` class.

```
class Person
{
    string _name;

public:
    Person(void) { _name = ""; }
    string Name(void) const;
};
```

AFAIK, an underscore is simply an indication of a private member, please correct me if i'm wrong. I'm not so sure of what the purpose of the rest of the code is. There are two public members, which I'm assuming are both methods in themselves. The first statement allows a `Person` to be created with a default `_name` of `""`. What is the purpose of the next line, and what is it returning, if nothing but a datatype? When and how can it be used?

Comment: Constructors don't have return types. Was that what was bothering you?

Comment: No offense, but this is a pretty basic question. I think you'd be best served by spending more time reading tutorials and writing code for practice, which will help you get a grasp of a lot of these details.

Comment: The next line is a member function, has nothing to do with the constructor. Like Borgleader said, a constructor ends without any `return`. And as far I know shouldn't even have a `void` as argument...

Comment: This seems to me a perfectly valid question for a beginner, even one who's giving an earnest effort to learn. Reading more basic material would have only made him or her _accustomed_, but imparted no _knowledge_, which this question is requesting. (Like with hindsight, it's hard to see from the perspective of the unknowing once blessed with knowledge.)

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK, an underscore is simply an indication of a private member

Well, the language does not require you to prefix your private members with an underscore. Some use it as a convention, but it's definitely not standard.

> There are two public members, which I'm assuming are both methods in themselves.

Yes, one is the *default-contructor* and the other is a *member function*. Both of which does not require the `void` argument (because we are not using C).

> The first statement allows a Person to be created with a default _name of "".

Technically the first one, the constructor, allows the creation of an object without specifying any argument. So that:

```
Person sophie;
```

is a valid declaration. The `_name` member object, in this case, is populated with an "empty" (let's not be pedantic on the null terminator) string.

It is to notice that the default *default-constructor* implicitly declared, is exactly the same (in this case) as the one declared in the class above. Therefore the constructor is actually useless in this particular context (as the default constructor for `std::string` will construct an "empty" string anyway).

> What is the purpose of the next line, and what is it returning, if nothing but a datatype? When and how can it be used?

The second member function is returning a `string` which I assume is an `std::string` (assuming the `std` namespace is imported into the scope using `using namespace std`). From the look of it it seems to be the classic "*getter*" member function that will return a copy of the `_name` member object.

Comment: Btw: `string s1; string s2("");` are guaranteed to have completely same in-depth structure? At least `s1.length() == s2.length()` and `s1 == s2` should be guaranteed, isn't it?

Comment: @mb84, yes, [it is guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK, an underscore is simply an indication of a private member [...]

This is not true. An underscore can be an indication of many things, not just access specification. It ultimately has to do with design choices the author of the code made. Private variables don't need to be prefixed with an underscore, but when they do, it could be for the intention of disambiguating the characteristics of the data member from other data members. In this case, an underscore prefix denotes a private access specification.

> What is the purpose of the next line, and what is it returning, if nothing but a datatype?

The next line is declaring a function named `Name` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `string`. This function is `const`-qualified, meaning it does not modify the state of `*this` (unless a data member is declared as `mutable`, then it may modify that variable).

> When and how can it be used?

It is a function, meaning after it has been defined, you may call it. From the looks of it, its definition could be as trivial as returning the private data member `_name` to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `string Name(void) const;` only **declares** a function named `Name` which returns a `string`. This line does *not* **define** what the function actually does. I assume that the code you posted here is in a .h header file. The code for the `Name` function is most likely in a corresponding .cpp file.